# CREG, CGREG, CEREG AT commands

Tags: mobile, at-command, modem

I have to control a modem Cinterion ELS61 with a host application. Can anyone tell me in simple words which is the real difference among at+creg?, at+cgreg? and at+cereg? commands?
I know that cgreg is related to 2G and 3G radio access technology and cereg with 4G/LTE one, but the actual differences are not so clear and neither the relation with the creg command results.
It follows an example from a real case:

```
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 2,5,"38AD","02531900",7
OK
AT+CGREG?
+CGREG: 2,4
OK
AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: 2,5,"2AF2","02531900",7
OK
```

What is the difference among the answers to +creg and +cereg? Aren't they quite the same? And by the way, what does it mean that the same cell (02531900) has 2 difference location area codes (i.e. 38AD and 2AF2)?
Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the `+C*REG` commands, as you probably know, query the status of the registration to *some* network.

The first step is the following categorization:

- `+CREG`, that queries the registration to the *circuit switched network*.
  It is basically the GSM "classic" network, on which voice/data calls and SMSs are based
- `+C*REG` commands, that query the registration to the *packet networks*.
  They are the networks on which the packed data traffic is based. The network allowing the access to internet, to be clear.

---

`+C*REG` commands are technology specific commands:

- `+CGREG` queries the registration to **G**PRS network
- `+CEREG` queries the registration to LTE data packet network, and in some cases is mandatory also to perform tasks that were usually based on GSM: voice calls (if VoLTE, Voice Over LTE, is supported) or to sent SMSs (IMS protocol).
  LTE technology, basically, moves almost everithing on packet traffic

---

The reason why different commands are available (even in the same cellular module) is that different registration processes are required for each sub-network.

Comment: My product uses CREG as "am I connected?" because I'd never seen a diff in CREG, CEREG, CGREG responses.  This is now a problem because AT&T is starting to sunset all circuit-switched services, so in testing I'm seeing CREG denied but CGREG and CEREG as success.  I have dozens of devices in customers' hands, so this is a big problem for me.  Don't be like me.

Comment: Until they're only dozens (and not millions) maybe you can act a "I update your FW" campaign? :)

Comment: Ha!  Luckily it's only dozens.  There are a few update paths including -I send them a phone to do the update -They use their phone to update -They use a windows machine -Mail the unit back <<eyeroll emoji>>

Comment: further information: https://onomondo.com/blog/at-command-cereg/#creg-vs-cgreg-vs-cereg